# Loopback with i18n support

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, loopbackjs

I'm trying to understand how to add i18n support to loopback which is built on top of express.js.

I've installed [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) and have read the express.js documentation. It looks like I don't want a global state of localization because I'll be serving HTTP responses. The i18n-node documentation recommends I attach it to the request object and gives an example.

My problem is that I can't find where/how to add this code into loopback. Everywhere I try to put the `app.configuration` function it says that method is undefined.

I have a feeling this is a middleware addition that I want to add to the middleware.json file in the routes phase. But I don't know how to do that.

Does anybody know a good way to internationalise a loopback app (server response messages, emails going out etc.)?

Comment: Did you figured out? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation on their [Github Page](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node). I think **the configuration code is best to keep in server/boot/ folder**. As these are loaded as the server start and then, can be used by other rest endpoints. Don't forget to add JSON files for translations.

I don't think there are any other requirements as LoopBack is built on top of Express and most of their codes work same.